# Superfish menu on mobile - touch a link and it loads the link (page) and the submenu at the same time

Tags: jquery, mobile, superfish

Superfish 1.75

HoverIntent 1.8.0

jQuery 1.10.2

Touching a menu item on mobile device using Superfish, the following behaviour is expected, as noted on Superfish website:

> **Supports touch devices.** On Android, iOS, Windows Phone 7 and IE10
>   (with touchscreen), first touch will open an associated submenu,
>   second will follow the link. Mouse and keyboard accessibility works as
>   normal. Note that you currently need to include Brian Cherne’s
>   hoverIntent plugin to support certain Android browsers' and IE10's
>   touch interaction. This may change.

However, the first touch will open the associated submenu and the link at the same time.

Tested using the menu located on the official site:
http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/

Shouldn't the behaviour be:

Touch 1: associated submenu opens

Touch 2: link associated from touch 1 menu item opens.

Thoughts?

Thank you.